# Unparseable Greek date - SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, locale, simpledateformat

I am trying to read a string that represents a Greek date-time (like "28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00") using `SimpleDateFormat`, but it throws a `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00"` error.

Here is a sample code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("el-GR");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm", locale);
try {
     sDate = (Date) formatter.parse("28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00");
 } catch (ParseException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I've also tried locales el and el_GR but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the encodings are right everywhere? Is Java definitely seeing the correct Unicode characters for "Μαρτίου"?

Comment: Yes, I've checked every option and encoding, system-locals etc seem to be fine. I've just noticed that it only works for dates like "28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00" with locale = el, but that's it, nothing else...

Comment: My mistake! I meant that it only works for dates like "28 Μάρτιος 2014, 14:00"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

a) First to say, never user the expression `new Locale("el-GR")`, instead use `new Locale("el", "GR")` or without country `new Locale("el")`, see javadoc for correct usage of constructors (because there is no language code "el-GR").

b) The exception you observe (and me, too, but not everyone) is caused by the different localization resources of the underlying JVM. Proof on my JVM (1.6.0_31):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("el");
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
for (String m : dfs.getMonths()) {
    System.out.println(m);
}

// output
Μάρτιος
Απρίλιος
Μάϊος
Ιούνιος
Ιούλιος
Αύγουστος
Σεπτέμβριος
Οκτώβριος
Νοέμβριος
Δεκέμβριος
```

The explanation of different data can be found in CLDR-repository for localized resources. Modern greek knows at least two different forms for the month March (Μαρτίου vs the standalone form Μάρτιος). Java-version 6 uses the standalone form while Java-version 7 uses the normal form.

See also this [compatibility note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) for java-version 8 where you have options to specify the format mode (standalone or not):

> When formatting date-time values using DateFormat and
>   SimpleDateFormat, context sensitive month names are supported for
>   languages that have the formatting and standalone forms of month
>   names. For example, the preferred month name for January in the Czech
>   language is ledna in the formatting form, while it is leden in the
>   standalone form. The getMonthNames and getShortMonthNames methods of
>   DateFormatSymbols return month names in the formatting form for those
>   languages. **Note that the month names returned by DateFormatSymbols
>   were in the standalone form until Java SE 7**. You can specify the
>   formatting and/or standalone forms with the Calendar.getDisplayName
>   and Calendar.getDisplayNames methods...

So the obvious solution would be **updating to Java 7**. External libraries will not help here because today there is no one which has its own resources for Greek. However, if you are forced for any reason to continue with Java 6 then following awkward workaround will help:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("el", "GR");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm", locale);
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
String[] months = {"Ιανουαρίου", "Φεβρουαρίου", "Μαρτίου", "Απριλίου", "Μαΐου", "Ιουνίου", "Ιουλίου", "Αυγούστου", "Σεπτεμβρίου", "Οκτωβρίου", "Νοεμβρίου", "Δεκεμβρίου"};
dfs.setMonths(months);
formatter.setDateFormatSymbols(dfs);

try {
     System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00"));
     // output in my timezone: Fri Mar 28 14:00:00 CET 2014
} catch (ParseException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Wow, extra credit for this thorough, well-documented, and excellent answer. I'm curious too if you can explain what "standalone form" means in such languages.

Comment: @BasilBourque English does not know any difference, but especially slavish languages like Russian etc. have different grammar forms if you use months names either in embedded context (in combination with other date components) or just "standalone" (i.e. as single caption of a calendar table). CLDR unicode consortium has invented this notation. In languages however, this is rather called "case" (nominative-standalone or genitive). "1st of May" would require in Russian the Genitive form of "May" while English here just use the combination "of" plus nominative ("Mays" does not exist in English).

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code works for me.
Double check the characters used. You problem was also a misspelled character

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("el", "GR");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm", locale);
    try {
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Ιανουάριος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Φεβρουάριος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Μάρτιος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Απρίλιος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Μάϊος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Ιούνιος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Ιούλιος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Αύγουστος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Σεπτέμβριος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Οκτώβριος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Νοέμβριος 2014, 14:00"));
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("28 Δεκέμβριος 2014, 14:00"));

     } catch (ParseException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Output :

```
Tue Jan 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Fri Feb 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Fri Mar 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Mon Apr 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Wed May 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Sat Jun 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Mon Jul 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Thu Aug 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Sun Sep 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Tue Oct 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Fri Nov 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
Sun Dec 28 14:00:00 IST 2014
```

Comment: I think you overlook the simple fact that using these month forms is not correct in normal formatting context from a grammar point of view. It is only okay if you use such labels as caption of columns etc. (standalone). Unfortunately Java 6 only knows standalone forms while Java 7 only knows the normal forms, Java 8 is clearly better.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("el", "GR");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm", locale);
try {
       Date sDate = formatter.parse("28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00");
       System.out.println(sDate);
} catch (ParseException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
```

In this blog you can get more information

https://grooovygeorge.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/why-simpledateformatter-isnt-really-simple-with-locales/

Comment: Hello Pablo and thank you. I had already seen this post but using new Locale(“el”, “GR”) didn't work as well. Did this finally worked for you with Greek and Finnish?

Answer (score -1):

```
String target = "28 Μαρτίου 2014, 14:00";
    Locale locale = new Locale("el", "GR");
    try
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm", locale);
        Date result =  df.parse(target);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch(ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It does for me did you copy paste the code?What error you get?